# DataTables Javascript AJAX with plain data array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax

I have an ajax call that returns:

```
[{"fields": 
    {"account_to": ["Bank Account - SECU", "11000"],
     "posted_by": 1, 
     "amount": "1000", 
     "created_date": "2015-07-31T14:53:03.766Z", 
     "posting_date": "2015-07-31T14:53:03.763Z", 
     "account_from": ["Consulting Income - ABC", "41000"], 
     "company": "S&S Co"},

     "model": "base.glentry", "pk": 8},
  {"fields": ...
]
```

Note that there is no: `{'data': [ data array ]}` which all the examples have.  I can find how to change the name so that 'data' can be something else, but how do I make it render like this with AJAX without manually processing the return value and wrapping the data?

Here is my javascript:

```
$('#dt').dataTable( {
    "processing": true,
    "ajax": "http://localhost:8000/gl/",
"columns": [
    {"": "fields.amount"}
]
} );
```

I've tried all sorts of things, but get the same result.  What can I do?

Comment: What do you need to do?

Comment: Work, I get an error

Comment: What error? What do you mean by 'render like this'?

Comment: Assuming you are going for server side processing with DataTables, the plugin is expecting a specific format of JSON to return. The "aoColumns" property is simply to assign property names and such to each column. Off the top of my head datatables processing will expect "aaData" to hold the json you have above.

Comment: http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html clic in the ajax tab below the datatable example to see the especific format of the json

Comment: I cannot change the JSON format.